# bat script to run diskpart from an USB stick to the X:/ drive

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'am trying to run a bat script in order to automate the process of rebuilding a workstation Win10 image from an USB stick. (Especially when I encounter any error from the Microsoft Endpoint Task Sequence).

I created a bat file like:

```
@ECHO OFF 
DISKPART
SELECT DISK 0
CONVERT GPT
CREATE PARTITION EFI SIZE=512
ASSIGN LETTER=S
FORMAT QUICK FS=FAT32
CREATE PARTITION MSR SIZE=128
CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY 
ASSIGN LETTER=C
FORMAT QUICK FS=NTFS
CREATE PARTITION EFI SIZE=512
```

I'm trying to find a way how to actually execute this whole bat script from the USB stick but apply it only the X:/ drive.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: `diskpart /?` mentions `/s <script> - Use a DiskPart script.`

Comment: How do you know that the disk is going to be `disk 0`, or what its existing partition type or structure is?

Comment: @Stephan - thanks for the input. Is the syntax correct as is above?